# What are advantages of using a HMAC over RSA with SHA-1 hashes?

Tags: rsa, signature, authentication, sha-1, hmac

I am currently studying for an exam and this was a previous question:

> Give one advantage of using HMACs over using RSA to sign SHA-1 hashes.

My thoughts are that it has something to do with the fact that HMAC assumes a private key has already been shared so there is no need to use public-private keys.  But wouldn't it be possible for this key to be compromised?

Comment: Advantages of HMAC are speed, as stated in the fine answers; and small size of the authenticating token (128 bits or even much less, vs at least 1024 bits). The obvious drawback of HMAC is that one needs a secret to verify that token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HMAC is much faster to compute. Also, HMAC might still be secure, even if the [underlying hash function is broken](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/why-does-a-broken-hash-function-undermine-an-hmac). This is not true for RSA + a broken hash function.

Comment: "Will probably be must"? What about "are much"? Smaller size is certainly true as well. This is a dumb question though, it all depends on the key management...

Comment: @owlstead HMAC is *much* faster - RSA is a very slow algorithm

Comment: @OwenOrwell Sorry for the misunderstanding, that was about a typo in the answer, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage is speed: HMACs are much faster than an RSA signature.

Given the question says you are signing SHA-1 hashes, there is no need to use a hash function in composition with RSA since the message will already be short-enough to sign directly. I doubt they are looking for an answer about the security of the underlying hash.